# Помогите нарисовать диаграмму базы данных

Tags: база-данных

У меня есть база магазина в котором можно арендовать лодку. По этому у нас есть таблички: клиент, адрес, лодка, работник, аренда. Один клиент и один работник может иметь несколько адресов. Далее таблица "аренда", я не могу понять ТОЧНО, какой вид связи существует между таблицами "клиент" и "аренда" И "работник" и "аренда", ведь один клиент может арендовать лодку несколько раз, то есть иметь несколько аренд, и одной аренде может принадлежать только один клиент, то есть выходит связь один-ко-многим, ведь так? Далее работник и аренда, один работник может иметь несколько аренд, но одна аренда может иметь только одного работника, правильно? Ну короче посмотрите, правильно ли я нарисовал диаграмму?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Лодка" и "аренда" неправильно вроде бы, ведь одной лодке может принадлежать несколько аренд, но одной аренде может принадлежать только одна лодка?

Comment: Вроде бы всё верно